# Обработчик событий для добавляемых в GridLayout кнопок

Tags: python, kivy

В цикле на Python добавляю в GridLayout кнопки, т.е. я не описываю их в файле .kv, а просто формирую список кнопок в зависимости от полученных в словарь данных из db:

```
for key in dict_values:
    self.parent.ids.table.add_widget(Button(text=key, background_color=dict_values[key]))
```

где table - это id-шник описанного в .kv файле лейаута.
Как мне повесить обработчик нажатия на кнопки (их более 100), чтобы после нажатия я смог получить, например text нажатой кнопки и color, и при желании изменить.
Если это можно описать в .kv файле, то очень прошу поделиться информацией

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось очень даже просто, сам разобрался, но возможно кому-то пригодится:

```
for key in dict_values:
    self.parent.ids.table.add_widget(Button(text=key, background_color=dict_values[key],
                                                    on_press=self.change_button_in_table))
```

где потом можно получить доступ к атрибутам через сущность:

```
    def change_button_in_table(self, instance):
        instance.background_color = [0.21, .12, 0.05, 1.0]
```